How to setup STM32 + libopencm3 on Windows
I am an electronic hardware engineer with experience and vendor specific IDEs. I am following this series.
I am following the steps mentioned on the GitHub to get started. BTW just want to mention I am new with Git, Make, etc.
I was able to clone the repo and was trying to make libopencm3 library. But I am getting following error:
PS C:\Users\Yash\OneDrive\Documents\workspace\bare-metal-series\libopencm3> make

'printf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. make: *** [include/libopencm3/stm32/f0/nvic.h] Error 1

I followed these instruction as well in README file of libopencm3

I made this change as it was highlighting as wrong "CompilerPath", as it was setup for Linux

But still I am getting same error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please do not post pictures of text ... post text instead
